# uart arm3 mss handler called twice after input

Tags: arm, serial-port, uart

**Original Question:**

*Why is my UART ARM3 mss function called twice ?*

**UPDATE: answer:**
*Because every incoming Byte will cause an interrupt. @ First interrupt 1 letter is inside. After the second interrupt already the rest data are inside.*

**New Problem:**
When I write a string: "test" and hitting enter in plink/putty:

- First time the ISR is called 't' is available in the buffer.

This is the debug picture:  [debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLrFE.png)

- Then next  time  'e','s','t','\n' is in the buffer.
  Here a similar screnshoot of "tatus\n" instead of "status\n" [tatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y85ul.png)

**Why is the first t overwritten?**

**Question**

( I right now saw that sometimes the full word is written into the buffer.
But not everytime.
I will try to record all incoming data until a '\n'  is decovered.  )

*** Where has the first 't' gone?**
*** Why is it overwritten?**

**UART init function:**

```
MSS_UART_init(&g_mss_uart0, MSS_UART_115200_BAUD, MSS_UART_DATA_8_BITS | MSS_UART_NO_PARITY);
```

**UART set handler function:**

MSS_UART_set_rx_handler(&g_mss_uart0, uart3_rx_handler, MSS_UART_FIFO_SINGLE_BYTE);

**And here is my handler description**
It prints the read out content..
Also it passes it to "command" and "value_str" variable for later processing..

```
Interrupt -> uart handler -> nothing
But it behaves like
Interrupt -> uart handler -> Interrupt -> uart handler -> nothing
```

**UART handler definition:**

```
void uart3_rx_handler(mss_uart_instance_t *this_uart)
{
    unsigned int rx_size = MSS_UART_get_rx(this_uart, g_rx_buff, sizeof(g_rx_buff));
    (void)rx_size;
    // int size  =(int)(rx_size);
    uart_calls_cnt++;

    uart_handler_flag = 0;
    // clear read in variables


    if (strchr((char *)g_rx_buff, '\n') != NULL) {


        // copy into read in variables
        memset(command, 0, 255);              // prepare command
        memset(value_str, 0, 255);            // prepare command
        strcpy(value_str, (char *)g_rx_buff);    // get user input into command
        strcpy(command, (char *)g_rx_buff);      // get user input into command
        value_str[strcspn(value_str, "\n")] = 0; // delete appended \n : works for LF, CR, CRLF, LFCR, ...
        command[strcspn(command, "\n")]     = 0; // delete appended \n : works for LF, CR, CRLF, LFCR, ...
                memset(&g_rx_buff[0], 0, 128); // clear rx buffer
        uart_handler_flag = 1; // so the while(1) loop @ scanf () will break and programm will proceed

    } else {
        // nothing..
    }
```

Comment: Your expectation is that the interrupt is triggered after you have pressed *Enter*. However, `MSS_UART_set_rx_handler()` takes the number of bytes that must be retrieved to trigger the interrupt and I guess you specified 1 as the *trigger* parameter. It doesn't care about *Enter*. It will trigger whenever the specified number of bytes have been received and the interrupt is not pending. So it is working as documented.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thank you a lot for your answer! Yesturday I was able to improve my code a bit with this information :D I hope I will improve it also today more :D I will also  look for a example^^